# in need of something more than wxPython wx.ComboBox control

Tags: wxpython

I'm in need of a combobox control that has features like the VBA combobox one.

What I can't seem to be able to squeeze out of wx.ComboBox are two things:

- have it handle multiple columns - depending on the selected item I need to have more data for that item to pass further on to different functions, as much as I could just use a dictionary and the selected checkbox item as the key for other values, I still need to display multiple values in the dropdown thing, think of it as column 1 holding some employee ID, column 2 holding his name etc. In VBA columns could have a specific width also, so one could "hide" certain "of use only to the developer" values in the item lists as well.
- a way to resize the dropdown menu - I need a LOT of these in multiple forms, different numbers of visible items upon 'dropdown' (so dropdown menu height actually), also adjust the dropdown width based on the mentioned columns, in VBA the parameters for these were things like ListWidth, ColumnCount, ColumnWidths.

A visual example of what I need

[image: vba combobox]

1. If I'm missing on how to make wx.ComboBox do what I want, please enlighten me.
2. If wx.ComboBox just can't cut it, perhaps there is some other wx control I do
   not know about, which could make all of that happen for me ?
3. If not, I imagine I'm stuck with extending some wx control, adding what I need to it ? I'm not too good at OOP but I guess there's always gotta
   be a first, if that's my only move then I'd at least like some
   advice on which control to best use as base. Should that happen I'll
   probably later on post my crappy code and ask for more help.
4. Hey, maybe all I am actually left with is completely making my own control based on this article ?
   http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls

OR maybe there's something like this already out there, made by someone, that I can just use ? I stumbled upon this one for example:
http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8561
But that's C++, which I unfortunately barely know, I'll probably sooner go with one of the mentioned steps than manage to port it to Python. Other than that I believe steps 1-4 are of increasing difficulty for me, so please advise as to how you would tackle the problem.

Any help welcome, as always. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ComboBox wraps the native widget, so it's pretty limited in what it can do. You won't be able to make it do most of what you want. However, it does allow you to store objects for each of the items within it via its Append method. You can read all about how that works at the following tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/16/wxpython-storing-object-in-combobox-or-listbox-widgets/

You can get similar functionality to what you want using the ComboCtrl, which is a generic combobox which allows a custom pop-up. You may be able to modify the pop-up itself to do what you want, although the samples in the wxPython demo are almost exactly what you're looking for. The only missing piece that I see is that the demo doesn't have a resizable pop-up.

Comment: Many thanks for the ComboCtrl tip. I managed to bend this setup to what I need - using a monospace font and passing the adodbapi 'resultset' to the constructor I auto-create columns I need, fill them, set widths to the largest element in column and based on that set the popup width. Setting the initial value for the ListCtrl in the popup class seems simple - I just set the .val and .curitem parameters to 0 (as I want the first element 'preselected'). But how can I make that value also appear in the ComboCtrl ? I mean right after showing the form, now it pops up as soon as I click the ComboCtrl

Comment: ah, ok, I got it. Not sure what I was doing wrong earlier, but I pulled it off. I added my own method **PreselectFirst(self)** and besides setting the before mentioned parameters I added a line **self.GetCombo().SetText(self.GetStringValue())**